# Rails won't load custom Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I just created a `/scripts` directory. Scripts are auto loaded with

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/scripts"]
config.eager_load_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/scripts"]
```

## Problem

Also there are scripts within `scripts/schemes/*.rb` which should be run but they are not.

*Example*. Write a sample script `scripts/schemes/write.rb` with

```
File.open('foo.txt', 'w') do |f|
  f.write('123')
end
```

and go to the console, `rails console`. You'll see no file with be created whereas `foo.txt` was expected to be created.

How can these files living in `scripts/schemes/` be executed at startup?

#### Failed attempts to solve the problem

- Have `/scripts/main.rb` requiring (`require`) or loading (`load`) the files at `scripts/schemes/*.rb`. *Clarification: since files were already loaded in application.rb `autoload_paths` Rails will throw an error.*
- Include `scripts/schemes` in `config.autoload_paths`. *Clarification: nothing changes.*

Comment: I followed your steps and `foo.txt` is being created as expected. Did you put the auto-load additions into `config/application.rb`? Maybe spring is causing an issue? Try `spring stop` before `rails console`.

Comment: Try to run `$ bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` in the console to see what paths is autoladed.

Comment: To add things to the path use `Rails.root.join('scripts')` as it's cleaner than the version you have here.

Comment: I followed the suggestions. They appear in autoload_paths, as pointed out by @peter-andersen, but are not loaded. Stopping spring also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out.

Turns out Rails loads classes and modules only when name *conforms* to the file name.

For example, `scripts/schemes/foo_name.rb` contents to be

```
module FooName
  # ...
end
```

or

```
class FooName
  # ...
end
```